# Swift ios working with unix timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp

My api return timestamp in unix eg: 1362873600

What I want to do is to convert **1362873600** into the format/remaining time eg:

**20 days 11 hours left**

Is there a built in method when working with unix timestamps. Or is there any library that can handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this:
(there might be a typo in there I was unable to test this)

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Full
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond
let string = formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(1362873600)
```

for Swift 2.0 I believe you need to change the allowUnits line to:

```
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnit.Day | NSCalendarUnit.Hour | NSCalendarUnit.Minute | NSCalendarUnit.Second
```

you can read more on formatters here: http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/

Answer (score 1):

First, create an NSDate with a time interval since 1970 - the Unix epoch date.

`let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1362873600)`

You can then compare that date to now to get the time remaining. To format the time remaining value as a string you would use an NSDateFormatter, for your needs you may need to create your own.